# Select duplicate values

Tags: sql-server, join, select, duplicates

```
table1  dorm_ID   Person_ID
          145       66689
          146       66692
          150       66585
          151       68989

table2    P1      P2    Relationship
         78989  66689      Roommate
         58596  66689      Bio teacher
         79858  66689      English teacher
         88859  66692      Roommate
         58597  66692      English teacher
         98557  66585      Roommate
         98999  68989      Chemistry teacher
         98992  68989      English teacher
```

I want to select the dorm_ID that has both Roommate and English teacher as relationship. I need to join the table on Person_ID= P2. Is there a way you can set up a query that select the duplicate values of dorm_id (if there is any) and then select only the ones with relationship "Roomate" or "English teacher".

My expected value:

```
   dorm_ID   Person_ID     P1     P2      Relationship
     145       66689      78989  66689      Roommate
     145       66689      79858  66689      English teacher
     146       66692      88859  66692      Roommate
     146       66692      58597  66692      English teacher
```

I have tried using queries involving HAVING COUNT(*) but that does not do the trick. I don not want the count of the duplicates, I want the duplicates grouped together.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the output you want, but it contains the same information:

```
select t1.dorm_id, t1.person_id,
       group_concat(distinct t2.p1),
       group_concat(distinct t2.p2)
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t2.p1 = t1.person_id 
group by t1.dorm_id, t1.person_id
having sum(case when t2.relationship = 'Roommate' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t2.relationship = 'English teacher' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Select 
  a.dorm_id, 
  a.person_id, 
  b.p1, 
  b.p2, 
  b.relationship 
FROM table1 a 
  JOIN (
    Select 
      p1, 
      p2, 
      relationship 
    FROM 
      (
        Select p2 
        FROM table2 
        WHERE relationship in ('Roommate', 'English teacher') 
        GROUP BY p2 
        HAVING count(*) > 1
      ) b 
      JOIN table2 c ON c.p2 = b.p2 
    WHERE c.relationship in ('Roommate', 'English teacher')
  ) d ON a.Person_ID = d.P2;
```